# Mutate a new variable using several conditions based on different variables

Tags: r, testing, mutate

I have this following dataframe representing responses from five individuals. There is four different responses Yes, No, Inc, Vag.

```
data_test = data.frame(Val_Av=c("Yes", "No", "Inc", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Inc", "Vag", "Yes"),
           Val_Am=c("No", "No", "No", "Inc", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Inc", "Vag", NA),
           Val_ZM=c(NA, NA, NA, "Yes", "No", NA, "No", "Inc", "Vag", "Yes"),
           Val_FC=c("No", "No", "No", NA, "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Inc", "No"),
           Val_CL=c("Yes", "No", "Inc", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", NA, NA, "Yes"))

  Val_Av Val_Am Val_ZM Val_FC Val_CL
1     Yes     No   <NA>     No    Yes
2      No     No   <NA>     No     No
3     Inc     No   <NA>     No    Inc
4     Yes    Inc    Yes   <NA>    Yes
5      No     No     No     No     No
6     Yes    Yes   <NA>    Yes    Yes
7      No    Yes     No    Yes     No
8     Inc    Inc    Inc    Yes   <NA>
9     Vag    Vag    Vag    Inc   <NA>
10    Yes   <NA>    Yes     No    Yes
```

I would like to create another variable summarising the responses following several rules

- If the response is the same in all the variables write the response (ex: line2 -> No, line5-> No, line6 -> Yes)
- If there is no Yes in the response, concat all the unique values (ex: line3 -> Inc;No, line 9 -> Vag;Inc)
- If there is a Yes in the responses AND

  ```
     - if there is strictly more Yes than other responses, write Yes (ex line 10 -> Yes, line4 -> Yes)
     - if there as much Yes as other responses, write "Dif" (Ex line 1-> Dif)
     - if there is strictly less Yes than other responses, concat all the unique value (Ex line8 -> Inc;Yes, line7->No;Yes)
  ```

In my real data, I have other variable that I don't want to take into account. Therefore I would like to find a way using across and start_with("Val_") functions.
I have no idea of how to proceed. I would appreciate any idea. Thanks

EDIT:

Using Friede code I tried to write a more simple code, but my trial is not working. Please see below what I have tried

```
data_test %>%
  mutate(Val=
    across(starts_with('Val_'), 
           function(x) case_when(
             length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) == 1 ~  unique(x[!is.na(x)]), 
             all(x != "Yes", na.rm = TRUE)  ~ paste(unique(x[!is.na(x)]), collapse = ";"), 
             any(x == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) & sum(x == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) == sum(x != "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) ~ "Dif", 
             any(x == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) & sum(x == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) > sum(x != "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) ~ "Yes",
             any(x == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) & sum(x == "Yes", na.rm=TRUE) < sum(x !="Yes", na.rm=TRUE) ~ paste(unique(x[!is.na(x)]), collapse = ";")
           )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for `dplyr::case_when()` - it's ideal for this type of hierarchical categorisation.  https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

Comment: Otherwise `apply(data_test, 1L, ...)` + nested `ifelse`. This is slow and often annoying to write down.

Comment: Thank you, what is difficult for me is to deal with is the way to write the different conditions. I know how to use the ifelse function (and I think I can manage with the case_when) but I don't know how to write the conditions. For condition 1 i would like to write something like across all the variable starting with "Val_" if all the variable are equal together ignoring NA write.... For the last conditions I don't know how to test if there is more Yes than other response etc...

Comment: @Av65 it might be helpful to give a complete expected output. Me and Friede have different outputs, and it's unclear to me which one is the expected one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know how to use the ifelse function (and I think I can manage with the case_when) but I don't know how to write the conditions.

Using base R I have explicitly rewritten your statements with `apply` and a nested `ifelse` statement. This is not the recommended approach in such cases.

```r
apply(data_test, 1L, \(x) 
      ifelse(length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) == 1L, 
             unique(x[!is.na(x)]), 
             ifelse(all(x != "Yes", na.rm = TRUE), 
                    paste(unique(x[!is.na(x)]), collapse = ";"),
                    ifelse(any(x == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) & sum(x == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) == sum(x != "Yes", na.rm = TRUE), 
                           "Dif", 
                           ifelse(any(x == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) & sum(x == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) > sum(x != "Yes", na.rm = TRUE), 
                                  "Yes", 
                                  paste(unique(x[!is.na(x)]), collapse = ";"))))))
#>  [1] "Dif"     "No"      "Inc;No"  "Yes"     "No"      "Yes"     "No;Yes" 
#>  [8] "Inc;Yes" "Vag;Inc" "Yes"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Does this get you started to write a more elegant and less redundant approach?

Havn't checked. If your statements do not cover every possibility, it is good to write another `ifelse` including a default, say, a `X`-flag. Notice that, `dplyr::case_when()` has a default option.

**Data**

```
data_test = data.frame(Val_Av=c("Yes", "No", "Inc", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Inc", "Vag", "Yes"),
                       Val_Am=c("No", "No", "No", "Inc", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Inc", "Vag", NA),
                       Val_ZM=c(NA, NA, NA, "Yes", "No", NA, "No", "Inc", "Vag", "Yes"),
                       Val_FC=c("No", "No", "No", NA, "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Inc", "No"),
                       Val_CL=c("Yes", "No", "Inc", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", NA, NA, "Yes"))
```

Comment: Thank you I will try to write a more elegant code using your R based approach

Comment: I edited my post with my attempt to write a better code using your R based approach but I am still stucked. I will try to find my error. Please note that in my real dataframe I have other variable that i don't want to take into account. That's why I am trying to use the function accross and start_with

Comment: You can test mine on your real data with `data$flag = apply(data[, grepl("Val_", colnames(data)], 1L, \(x) ...)`

Comment: This is working but i modify like this : data_test$new_variable = apply(data_test[, grepl("Val_", colnames(data_test)], 1L, \(x) ...) because in your command It doesn't create a new variable.

Comment: In my answer? This is intended. In the comment? It does. Called `flag`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of doing it, that is hopefully a little easier to understand, using `pmap()`:

```
data_test |>
  mutate(Output = pmap(across(starts_with("Val_")), ~{
    y = sum(c(...) == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE)
    ny = sum(c(...) != "Yes", na.rm = TRUE)
    case_when(
      length(unique(c(...))) == 1 ~ c(...)[1],
      !y | y < ny ~ paste(unique(c(...)) |> na.omit(), collapse = ";"),
      y > ny ~ "Yes",
      y == ny ~ "Dif")}))
```

Output:

```
   Val_Av Val_Am Val_ZM Val_FC Val_CL  Output
1     Yes     No   <NA>     No    Yes     Dif
2      No     No   <NA>     No     No      No
3     Inc     No   <NA>     No    Inc  Inc;No
4     Yes    Inc    Yes   <NA>    Yes     Yes
5      No     No     No     No     No      No
6     Yes    Yes   <NA>    Yes    Yes     Yes
7      No    Yes     No    Yes     No  No;Yes
8     Inc    Inc    Inc    Yes   <NA> Inc;Yes
9     Vag    Vag    Vag    Inc   <NA> Vag;Inc
10    Yes   <NA>    Yes     No    Yes     Yes
```

Comment: Thank you. The method works well but I do not understand the use of pmap. Can you give me more details ? Also, I am not used to this c(...). I assume this correspond to the variable selected by accross(starts_with()) function. Are there other cases we can use this ?

Comment: yes, your intuition is right. pmap is similar to map, or apply, or map2, but it works on an arbitrarily long list of items. c(...) selects all items in the list. For more information, consider reading the documentation of pmap